# Explode filename in PHP to use parts of it

Tags: php, explode

I want to display parts of a filname which is stored inside an array.
At the moment, I'm using filenames like this:

```
Brand-Product-Variation-ID-EAN-SKU-1.jpg
Brand-Product-EAN-SKU-24.jpg
Brand-Product-SKU-100.jpg
```

I need the filename in this format:

```
Brand-Prdocut-Variation-ID-EAN-SKU-{col}.jpg
```

The filename could be different mit more or lesse "-". So I always need the last number of the filename after the last "-".

I know that there is a function in PHP to explode a filename or text. 
But I don't know how to use it for the last "-".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get part before the last "-"

```
$arr = explode('-' , 'Brand-Prdocut-Variation-ID-EAN-SKU-1.jpg');  
$val  = $arr[ count($arr) -1 ];

// $val this is your value before the last "-"
```

Comment: sorry, I don't get it :( How could I display the whole filename in two steps? Like `<?php echo $before; ?>-<?php echo $after; ?>.jpg`

Comment: actually the explode function break the provided string with the character you provide .. and make an array of the string before and after  the character in our case the character will is `"-"`

Comment: in php you can simplly concatinate the string by using a " . " so you sould write something like `<?php $before . $after ?>`

Comment: ahh . it was a mistake actually you have to do `$arr[ count($arr) -2 ]`

Comment: `$arr = explode('-' , 'Brand-Prdocut-Variation-ID-EAN-SKU-1.jpg');  
$before  = $arr[ count($arr) -2 ];

$after =  (explode( '.' , end( $arr ))) [0];

echo $before .  $after;` here you go the whole code

Comment: it thought you want SKU1 .. what exactly you want out off the string ?

Comment: I want to build the filename with php like this: `Brand-Prdocut-Variation-ID-EAN-SKU-{col}.jpg` or in php: `<? echo $before; ?>-{<? echo $after; ?>}.jpg`

Comment: `$arr = explode('-' , 'Brand-Prdocut-Variation-ID-EAN-SKU-1.jpg');  
array_pop( $arr );
$before  = implode( '-' , $arr ) ;

$arr = explode('-' , 'Brand-Prdocut-Variation-ID-EAN-SKU-1.jpg');  
$after =  (explode( '.' , end( $arr ))) [0];


echo $before .  "-{" . $after . "}.jpg";`

Comment: i didnt get it earlier that you want everything before the last "-"

Answer (score 1):

you can use the php `explode`

```
// it will return  an array of '-' seperated values
  $arr= explode('-' , 'Brand-Prdocut-Variation-ID-EAN-SKU-1.jpg');

  // it will return  the index value which is  "1.jpg" in your case 
 $val = end($arr)
  $arr = explode('.' , $val);

 // this is your answer in the col which is "1" in your case
    $col = $arr[0];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how could I display the part from before the last "-"? I need to combine these to parts.

Comment: to get the part before the last "-" it is a bit of code i'll write it in an answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
$ss="Brand-Product-SKU-100.jpg";
preg_match("/[A-Za-z-]{1,100}-([0-9]{1,5}).[A-Za-z]{1,3}/",$ss,$kk);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($kk);
echo "</pre>";
```

100 means max length of file name can be. (max length of "Brand-Product-SKU-100")
5: max length of numbers taht  we want to get for example (max length of "100")
1,3: length file extension can be 1 or 2 or 3

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Brand-Product-SKU-100.jpg
    [1] => 100
)
```